# Voltar a apresentar o resultado com virgula após marcar ou desmarcar os valores dos checkbox

Tags: jquery

Eu sei que existe o replace mas não consigo aplicar para que o total seja apresentado com virgula após marcar ou desmarcar os checkbox.

```js
$(function(){
  total = document.getElementById('total');
  $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click',function(){
 
 var valTotal = total.value;
  
 valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',','.'));
  
 var valInput = (this.value);
  
 valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',','.'));
  
 var novoTotal=0;
 total.value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat(( valTotal + valInput )).toFixed(2) : parseFloat(( valTotal - valInput )).toFixed(2) ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,45" />2,45<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,50" />2,50<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
 <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa um replace assim:

```
total.value = value.replace('.', ',');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  total = document.getElementById('total');
  $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click', function() {

    var valTotal = total.value;

    valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',', '.'));

    var valInput = (this.value);

    valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',', '.'));

    var novoTotal = 0;
    var value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat((valTotal + valInput)).toFixed(2) : parseFloat((valTotal - valInput)).toFixed(2);
    total.value = value.replace('.', ',');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,55" />2,55<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,45" />2,45<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,50" />2,50<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2,00" />2,00<br/>
  <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00" />
</form>
```

Comment: Putz, simples assim!! valeu!!